Excel VBA - Application Run
The code below works
Sub RunMacrosInWorkbook2()

    Dim aRng As String, Sname1 As String

    'Cell A1 contains the name of the Workbook 2 to open
    Sname1 = Sheets("SelectPick3Games").Range("Q30").Value


    'Open Workbook 2
    Workbooks.Open (Sname1)

    Sheets("Dashboard").Select

    'run 1st macro in workbook 2
    Application.Run "NewJersey.xlsm!ClearPreviousResults1"

    'run 2nd macro in workbook 2
    Application.Run "NewJersey.xlsm!CopyStringsData1"

    'Save and Close Workbook 2
    ActiveWorkbook.Close True


    Windows("Pick3Stats.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("SelectPick3Games").Select
    Range("Q28").Select

End Sub

How can I get the following lines of code below if I substitute Sname1 for NewJersey.xlsm?
For example, the code below does not work
'run 1st macro in workbook 2
Application.Run "Sname1!ClearPreviousResults1"

'run 2nd macro in workbook 2
Application.Run "Sname1!CopyStringsData1"

Sname1 is what workbook name is in cell Q30
Cell Q30 = NewJersey.xlsm

I've tried different variations in Application.Run without any success.
There are a total of 42 workbooks used in cell Q30
I tried different code variations, but keep getting the same error.
What is the correct syntax for the Application.Run that will run the code in a second workbook?

In general you build (concatenate) the needed string from your variable and literal text. In other words, you can't just put sname1 in the string, as in "abcSNAME1def", it has to be a string created from your variable: "abc" & SNAME1 & "def"
So in your case this is the fixed up code:
Dim command as string 
command = sname1 & "!ClearPreviousResults1"
Application.Run command

If you feel more confident you can probably skip the extra variable:
Application.Run sname1 & "!ClearPreviousResults1"

But personally I find VBA a little unreliable in using complicated expressions as arguments in function calls and sometimes using a variable as in the first example works better if you find the "one-liner" approach is causing problems.

Thank you topsail.  Code modification works perfectly.  Appreciate all your help
